# Extract the Value of a webpage title by scraping the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im very new to Python/Coding so please bare with me.

However, I'm trying to extract the text from the title of a webpage *(input by the user)*, by scraping the 'webelement' of the page and finding its value using Selenium.

However, it keeps just returning the value 'none', instead of what I would expect to see (in this case 'BLACK BELTED WRAP COAT'.

Code can be found below:

---

```
title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/a/h2'))
```

*//rest of code hidden but if you need more, please do let me know. *(I'm new and don't want to spam)**

---

Any idea what's causing this?

The source URL I'm entering is: https://www.riverisland.com/p/black-belted-wrap-coat-782866

This runs without error, but returns an unexpected value (as seen in below images).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KdCy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Kct.png)

Appreciate it and apologies if I've missed anything.
Ginge

Comment: Have you double-checked the second argument that you are providing in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find an element use `find_element` instead of `find_elements` . `find_elements` will return a list of webelements.

Try with below code:

```
Imports required for Explicit waits
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.riverisland.com/p/black-belted-wrap-coat-782866")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Click on Accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"accept-all"))).click()

title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[@data-localize='Product_Title']")))
print(title.text)
```

```
BLACK BELTED WRAP COAT
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text *`BLACK BELTED WRAP COAT`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.product-title.ui-product-title").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='product-title ui-product-title']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='accept-all']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.product-title.ui-product-title"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@name='accept-all']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='product-title ui-product-title']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Console Output:

```
BLACK BELTED WRAP COAT
```

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: So that has helped massively and I've gone with: 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
title = print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='product-title ui-product-title']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")).

However, that spits out a timeout error. raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: @tisGinge _TimeoutException_ was due to the presence of the _Accept Cookie_ button which you need to click. Now I have added a line to handle that even.